# Filter and map and keep original

Tags: json, dictionary, filter

I have following structure:

```
this.pronos = [{
    "id": 1,
    "eventname": "EVENT1",
    "round": "EVENT1-1",
    "factor": 1,
    "matchPassed": 10,
    "matchs": [{
        "eq1": "EQ1",
        "eq2": "EQ2",
        "scoreEq1": 0,
        "scoreEq2": 3,
        "passed": true,
        "stats": {
            "domicile": 35.29,
            "exterieur": 35.29,
            "nul": 29.41,
            "boosted": 1
        },
        "date": 20190809,
        "friendlyDate": "Vendredi  9 ao\u00fbt 2019 20:45",
        "pronos": [{
            "matchId": 10,
            "userId": 1,
            "username": "Marcel",
            "points": 0,
            "validation": true,
            "pronoEq1": 1,
            "pronoEq2": 0,
            "booster": 0,
            "MR": 0
        },
        ...
        ]
    },
    ...
    ],
},
    ...
]
```

I would like to keep original array and return this filtered and mapped array.

```
getNextPronos() {
    return this.pronos.filter(event => {
      return event.matchs
        .some(match => {
          return match.date >= this.recentDate;
        });
    })
      .map(event => {
        event.matchs = event.matchs.filter(match => {
          return match.date >= this.recentDate;
        });
        return event;
      }).filter((event) => {
        return event.matchs.length > 0;
      });
  }
```

I don't want to declare new array, because `this.pronos` will be modified later.

Comment: FWIW: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: So the issue currently is that you're modifying the `event` objects and you don't want to do that?

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the issue you have at the moment is that you're modifying the `event` objects, but you want to leave them untouched. If so:

```
getNextPronos() {
    return this.pronos
        // Only events where at least one match is after the date
        .filter(({matchs}) => matchs.some(({date}) => date >= this.recentDate))
        // Map to new event objects with filtered `matchs`
        .map(event => ({
            ...event,
            matchs: event.matchs.filter(({date}) => date >= this.recentDate)
        }));
}
```

This does one partial loop through the `matchs` to see if any match is after the date, then a second full loop later to filter out the ones before the date. That seems fine to me. The alternative is to create new event objects for all the events before filtering some of them out, which looks like this:

```
getNextPronos() {
    return this.pronos
        // Map to new event objects with filtered `matchs`
        .map(event => ({
            ...event,
            matchs: event.matchs.filter(({date}) => date >= this.recentDate)
        }))
        // Filter out the (new) events that have no `matchs`
        .filter(({matchs}) => matchs.length);
}
```

---

Side note: The plural of "match" is "matches" (with an "e").